# Finding Thriller/Murder - Mystery Novel involving a girl who forgets the killer due to shock

Tags: identification-request

I have read this book twice. This book is about a girl who babysits a neighbour's baby, and saves the baby from a serial killer.  She confronts the killer, but due to the shock/trauma of being in that incident she forgets the face of the killer. She seeks psychiatric treatment to find the killer.

But the killer is really

> the doctor.

This book has a purple cover featuring a house. The title may be *The Dark* or similar. I have searched countless books regarding this name but found nothing on it.

Some more details about the book:

The attempt of the murder took place on night with clouds and lightning. Not sure if there was rain. The killer had a pistol in his hand and was descending down the stairs, when the girl sees his face in a flash of lightning. Earlier, the girl goes into the upper room when the lights are cut off by the killer. The baby she later saves is in the living room downstairs. She remembers that the baby is in the house and rushes downstairs. I think she takes the baby and is going to go hide upstairs when she sees the killer.

This book was probably from 2002-2010, it was an American teen fiction novel, set in the 21st century America.  I read it in American English.

Comment: Welcome to Literature.SE! Can you provide some more information? Such as when you read the book, and what language? Was it an adult book or teen fiction?

Comment: I read it years ago...It was in english, teen fiction.
Also the cover had lightning along with the house being shown.
The girl had a boyfriend who was tortured by some thugs by covering him up with bird feathers and burning those with cigarettes. This is all I remember.

Comment: @RushikeshWarde Is ‘years ago’ four years or twenty four? Was it in British English,  American English or Australian? What country was it set in? What time period was it set in? Did it feel contemporary or dated?

Comment: I am sorry for not specifying. I read it between from 2002-2010. It was in American English. Set in America too I think. 21st Century. I just remembered some details, I will edit the question now.